# Can't remove the space where the Date-picker Label was supposed to be

Tags: css, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I am trying to remove the extra space where the label was supposed to be (the green part)[image]

This seems to be the CSS for the date-picker, now here comes the problem :
[image]

I added this in the .css file, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex {
padding-top: 0.0em !important;
padding-right: 0.0em !important;
padding-bottom: 0px !important;
padding-left: 0.0em !important; 
}
```

Yes, the CSS file is linked to the html file, when I try to modify something else it works.

Any ideas why?

EDIT: I am using the Angular Material Date-picker

This is the HTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate formControlName="from" placeholder="From">
    <input matEndDate formControlName="to" placeholder="To">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.from.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid starting date!</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.to.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid ending date!</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What datepicker are you using? Where is the HTML?

Comment: @berkobienb Angular Material Date-picker, I edited the question and added the HTML

Comment: Try and remove the .mat-form-field-appearance-fill class and just use: mat-form-field-flex. So something like this:

`.mat-form-field-flex {
padding-top: 0.0em !important;
padding-right: 0.0em !important;
padding-bottom: 0px !important;
padding-left: 0.0em !important; 
}`

Comment: @berkobienb doesn't work, tried it already. It's really strange that I cannot modify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS rules are correct. You are most likely running into view encapsulation issues.

If you are using the CSS file defined by your `styleUrls` array in your component, your rules will not pierce through to the Angular component. You can get around this in two ways.

1. Move your rules to a top level css/scss file.
2. Use the `::ng-deep` pseudo-class to apply the rule from your component. (I'd recommend nesting this in the `:host` pseudo-class to limit your scope).

   ```
   :host ::ng-deep .your-class {
        // rules
   }
   ```

Here is a StackBlitz to show both these methods working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvn3gy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-comparison-example.css